# how to remove garbage data from http response

Tags: c++, json, boost-asio

am working on a win32 c++ code using boost asio that gets information from a server. The code works well when i use LOCALHOST but when i connect to an online server the response has integers added to the beginning and end of the JSON response

the code works well with localhost doesn't with an online server. Am wondering if its something wrong with my http settings

http settings are

```
string str = formData(data);
std::ostream request_stream(&request_);
request_stream << "POST " << path << " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
request_stream << "Host: " << server << "\r\n"; 
request_stream << "User-Agent: C/1.0\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
request_stream << "Content-Length: " << str.length() << "\r\n";
request_stream << "Accept: */*\r\n";
request_stream << "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
request_stream << str ;
```

expected output is:
{"success":-2,"message":"no username"}
The output i get is:
26

{"success":-2,"message":"no username"}

0

The 26 and 0 is the garbage data

Comment: No, it's not garbage data. It's HTTP. It's a complicated protocol. Use an HTTP library.

Comment: Insufficient information. What server? What app protocol? What library handles the HTTP response? How do you decode it? This _could_ be an artefact of chunked transfer-encoding. It could be something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP reply uses chunked transfer-encoding (check the options in the reply header).

In this case you have to

1. read a line of text
2. interpret its content as an hexadecimal integer
3. extract exactly this amount of bytes (partial content of the reply)
4. repeat from step 1 until the integer value is 0

Comment: Or, alternatively, use an HTTP library, which fully understands and implements HTTP, to handle both sending and receiving HTTP content.

Comment: am able to read the header with     while (std::getline(response_stream, header) && header != "\r")

Comment: @Berniegach then if in these lines extracted from the reply header you find something like `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, this means you have to switch to the solution given in this answer.

Comment: and reading the content i use  // Continue reading remaining data until EOF.
  boost::asio::async_read(socket_, response_,
   boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
   boost::bind(&Connection::handle_read_content, this,
    boost::asio::placeholders::error));

Comment: Please [see RFC 2616](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) for complete specifications of HTTP. You're not going to learn how to correctly implement HTTP by asking one question at a time, like this, but only by reading the formal technical specifications of this protocol, and writing your code accordingly if you wish to parse HTTP yourself, instead of using one of many HTTP client libraries that exist and do this correctly, already.

Comment: @Berniegach reading until EOF only works if the connection will be closed by the server. You should find `Connection: close` in the reply header.

Comment: Don't forget the optional chunk extension.